# How to fill the space between two text elements with dots in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show data like this:

```
Burger..........................$9.99
Steak and Potato...............$14.99
Mac and Cheese..................$6.99
```

How can I implement it in Flutter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as an option

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Burger'),
          Expanded(child: Text('.' * 100, maxLines: 1)),
          Text('\$9.99'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use fDottedLine package https://pub.dev/packages/fdottedline to draw a dotted line in any form.

```
 : Row(
    children: [
      Text('Burger'),
      FDottedLine(
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 160.0,
        strokeWidth: 2.0,
        dottedLength: 10.0,
        space: 2.0,
      ),
      Text('\$9.99'),
    ],
  ),
```

You have to give the dynamic widgth using MediaQuery

[image: Output]